# Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip'

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am a greenhorn in gradle and i just tried to create a new Android Gradle Project in IntelliJ. After filling up the necessities it started to download something which took hours so i decided to force quit my IDE and open the project again.

And now I am getting this:
[image]

And when I open the IDE logs, I see this:

```
2014-12-13 22:27:37,940 [103759372]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at '/Users/ramswaroop/Documents/My Workspace/PopoPics' 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:124)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:177)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:63)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:363)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:335)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:214)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:95)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:475)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:552)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:621)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$3.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:194)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.a(ProgressManagerImpl.java:281)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:233)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:181)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$9.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:530)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileChannelImpl.java:1166)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SharedFileLockTable.add(FileChannelImpl.java:1068)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:868)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:962)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:51)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:118)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
2014-12-13 22:27:37,941 [103759373]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip'. 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip'.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:401)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:309)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:164)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:164)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:369)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:335)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:214)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:95)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:475)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:552)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:621)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$3.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:194)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.a(ProgressManagerImpl.java:281)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:233)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:181)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$9.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:530)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)

2014-12-13 22:27:37,942 [103759374]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2014-12-13 22:27:37,942 [103759374]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip'.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

*INFO: Running on Mac Yosemite with Gradle 2.2 and IntelliJ IDEA 14 Ultimate.*

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It could be that the `gradle-2.1` distribution specified by the wrapper was not downloaded properly. This was the root cause of the same problem in my environment.

Look into this directory:

```
ls -l ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/
```

In there you should find a `gradle-2.1` folder.
Delete it like so:

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.1-bin/
```

Restart IntelliJ, after that it will restart the download from the beginning and hopefully work.

Comment: tanks, man, if help, just try to sync project again and its work, so you does not need to restart your IDE, but if necessary to restart, ok restart it

Comment: As well as doing this, it's worth clicking the URL in the error message to check if you can download the zip file via the browser. Turns out I couldn't because of the network I was on which was blocking that URL.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I had to remove all gradle files (wrapper, daemon and caches), And then i selected the "invalidate caches and restar" option

Comment: Thanks! I also tried with just a gradle sync after deleting the folder, and it worked!

Answer (score 32):

If you are on Windows, you can go to:

> **C:\Users\{your_name}\.gradle**

And delete all the references of the gradle package you can find in those folders:

1. caches
2. daemon
3. wrapper

Then re-open your project and sync gradle

Comment: Hi, I am getting Exception --Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip'. I have tried with above solution but didn't worked.Please help me on this.

Comment: Hi, no need to delete all these files, just delete C:\Users\User\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.4-all and proceed to sync

Comment: @Naveen Also try to Run your Android Studio as Administrator, I've spend days and hours to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 24):

1  Close Android Studio (AS)

2   Delete the folder in C:\Users\ *username* \ .gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.1-all

3   Run as admin

4   Sync your project files

Comment: I did not have that folder in the dists folder, for me it was simply to run AS as administrator.

Answer (score 12):

First check your Internet conection..

*or try with*

**Tools -> Android -> Sync**

*or Try*

**File -> Settings -> Gradle -> Check Offline Work**

[image]

Comment: I have no option called `Sync` under `Tools > Android` in IntelliJ. And of course I am connected to internet. Did u check the logs?

Comment: I have all other options except `Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Comment: Ok... can you find out any ICON of Sync ?

Comment: Hey, I don't know how but my gradle started working. Anyways, thank you very much for your time. But still I haven't figured out the root cause.

Comment: I connected to internet and restart the android studio and the gradle file auto downloaded, Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I cannot believe the below solution, but it did solve it.
in gradle-wrapper.properties file:
change

`distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

to

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

Comment: Just had this issue importing an old project. Apprently, gradle discontinued their http links. In my case I was dealing with gradle-1.10-all.zip

Comment: In my case, It could not download at all. I downloaded manually and set the url as shown here pointing to a local file with `file\://...`.

Answer (score 5):

you should also check if you are connecting via proxy. If there is a proxy set it up using File > Settings > Appearance and Behavior > System settings > HTTP Proxy

Comment: In my case it was a proxy issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
(My problem is with gradle 4.4 files)

Actually the problem is incorrect downloading of 4.4 gradle which already I had. 
When I delete gradle 4.4 version
`C:\Users\$Your_User\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.4-all`

Android studio again downloads gradle-4.4 and syncs with my project.

Now it had rectified with the help of Michelin Man

Thanks for your answer Michelin

Comment: Hi, I am getting Exception --Could not install Gradle distribution from 'services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip'. I have tried with above solution but didn't worked.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip

open this link in the browser and download the zip file and extract it to folder

Before extraction please delete the old folder whose name ends gradle-2.1-all and then you can start extracting

if you are window user extract it to this folder

C:\Users{Your-Name}.gradle\wrapper\dists

after that just restart your android studio. 
I hope it works it works for me .

Comment: Hi, I am getting Exception --Could not install Gradle distribution from 'services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip'. I have tried with above solution but didn't worked.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was just close the android studio and **restart as Administrator**.

Answer (score 3):

If all above solutions is not working and In case of your project was working fine and now getting this issue, then try this,

- go to android studio setting.
- select gradle under build,execution.
- then again just set path of gradle user home
  (C:/Users/%user_name%/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.5-bin)
- just rebuild again, this helps me.

Comment: This was the issue for me. I had a separate path which I put in there by mistake earlier. Changing gradle user home to the above path solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the corresponding Gradle version was not downloaded properly.

You could delete the broken file at

```
rm -rf .gradle/wrapper/dists/
```

and restart studio.

or try

```
File -> Settings -> Gradle -> Check Offline Work
```

and download the file from the official site and extract to the destination location

```
.gradle/wrapper/dists/
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that I was not connected to the same VPN with which I installed Android Studio, I do not know why it happens, but even if I have internet access, if I am not connected to the original VPN, the downloads from IDE do not work correctly.

I connected the VPN, I did the gradle again and finally it started to download and install everything correctly.
I also checked that I didn't go through any proxy or anything similar in my Android configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this same error, but it was due to an outbound firewall / monitoring tool silently killing the download requests in the background.

Sometimes the problem isn't Android Studio or your gradle configuration at all!

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, if you open the Design window for the app, there is error message about Gradle being not synched properly. Next to the error, there is a 'Try Again' button. If you click on that, Android studio tries to sycn up again.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to go to

`File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle`

and then I changed the `Service directory path`, which was pointing to a wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete `.gradle` data
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> then navigate to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Compiler** then check "*Sync project with gradle before building, if needed*".

My problem was fixed with this method.

Answer (score 1):

Change the *distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-bin.zip* from the **Your project folder\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties** to new one.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me is

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2.2-all.zip
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more reason for this error (assuming that gradle properly setup) is incompatibility between andorid.gradle tools and gradle itself - check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41609098/5151575) for the complete compatibility table.

In my case the error was the same as in the question and the stacktrace as following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$configureProject$1(BasePlugin.java:436)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    ...
```

I've fixed that by upgrading `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to the current latest `3.1.4`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}
```

Gradle version is 4.6

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in IntelliJ. It was working from command line though.

I found the issue was because of an improper Gradle config in the IDE. I wasn't using the "default Gradle wrapper" as recommended:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On MAC Remove gradle-2.1-all folder from the following path /Users/amitsapra/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.1-all and then try gradle build again. I faced same issues with 5.4.1-all.

It takes a little time but fixes everything

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason is that the gradle.zip IDE downloaded is broken (I cannot uncompress it manually), and following steps help.

1. gradle sync, and it says `could not install from ${link}, ${gralde.zip} ...`
2. download from ${link} manually
3. go to the ${gradle.zip}'s location
4. replace the ${gradle.zip} with the one downloaded, remove the `.lck` file on the same path.
5. gradle sync.

Note:

- ${link} is something like `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip`
- ${gradle.zip} looks like `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-${version}-all/${a-serial-string}/gradle-${version}-all.zip`

Answer (score 0):

I have also recieved this issue inside of InteliJ.

Go to the gradle/wrapper folder and modify distributionUrl inside of gradle-wrapper.properties to a correct version.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Answer (score 0):

It also disturb me a lot but now it is fine
The solution is very simple (written blow) **[window (android studio)]**

1. go to **C:\Users\your user name.gradle**
2. open **wrapper/dists** and delete the folder that is distrubing you in my case **--gradle-6.5--**
3. then go back to **.gradle** folder and this time open **daemon folder** and delete the folder with same number that is disturbing you in my case **--6.5--**
4. Then again go back to **.gradle** folder and this time open **caches folder** and delete the folder with same number that is disturbing you in my case **--6.5--**
5. now if your android studio is open then close it and again start it but this time with **administrator mode** by right clicking on the icon of android studio icon it is important
6. you should have internet connection and now your android studio will setup every thing by its own (please don't distrub it while it is doing its operation)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by downloading zip file from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip manually, put it inside `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle`, and sync.

Answer (score 0):

(Only for Mac Users)
download the gradle file from the link and then close the project then at the front page ,under the creat project option there is option called Import project(Gradle,Eclipse ADT,etc) here you have to select the gradle file which you have downloded earlier .
Then restart the Android studio .....hope your problem is solved now

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved the problem with

1. Ctrl + Shift+ F
2. Type 2.1 or just type the version of the gradle that can't be installed
3. replace the version of gradle with the correct one in the gradle-Wrapper.properties
   File in my case I replaced it with 6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Guys In my case the gradle is not properly install thats why this issue is happan with me.

Resolution:

1. Go to User Directory
2. Then Go to .gradle\wrapper\dists
3. Remove the folder which you are facing error
4. Invalidate cache and restart your android studio

Answer (score 0):

1. Download directly from Gradle: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/
   Choose the relative version, pay attention to the name behind the version
2. Open the folder
   as shown
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB7Ha.png)
   You can delete the contents in the wrapper folder before, replace it with the Gradle file you just downloaded, and unzip it. After unzipping, you can delete the compressed file.
3. Open Gradle settings. Modify the path problem, and then synchronize it. There should be no problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me on windows 10.

Close my project.
Close Android Studio.
Run Android Studio.
Open project.

Android studio takes a few minutes while everything sorts itself out.

I thought that maybe Android Studio just needed sufficient rights to extract and put the files in all the right locations and possibly set the path variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Add username and password in distributionUrl:**

```
distributionUrl = https://username:password@artifactory.trusted.visa.com/vdca-mobile-maven/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

**Note:**
no need to encoded base64 for either username or password.

TL:DR

I encountered the issue when I tried to download gradle in android studio from our custom maven artifactory.

It forbids 'anonymous' access of artifacts in Artifactory

> This initiative aims to disable 'anonymous' access of artifacts in
> Artifactory and enforces users to authenticate to read any artifact
> from Artifactory.  This is done for obvious security reasons and to
> create an audit trail for artifacts accessed.

I can verify it when I open logs of Android Studio
idea.log (Help -> Show log in Finder)

```
2021-09-08 16:05:46,759 [2335097]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://artifactory.trusted.visa.com/vdca-mobile-maven//gradle-5.4.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution.getToolingImplementationClasspath(DistributionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:86)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.lambda$run$0(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://artifactory.trusted.visa.com/vdca-mobile-maven/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1900)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionInstaller$1.run(DistributionInstaller.java:128)
```

After I add the username and password, I can see the log:

```
2021-09-08 16:44:56,253 [ 346318]   INFO -                         STDOUT - Downloading https://artifactory.trusted.visa.com/vdca-mobile-maven/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip 
2021-09-08 16:44:56,215 [ 346280]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started single-variant sync with Gradle for project 'VMCP'.
```

Gradle is downloaded to here.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:vdca_android_20_10_08_pr zgong$ ls -la ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.4.1-all/2oog0xj75bs1j4pttjqi636mc/
total 260960
drwxr-xr-x   6 zgong  VISA\Domain Users        192 Sep  8 16:46 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 zgong  VISA\Domain Users        160 Sep  8 16:44 ..
drwxr-xr-x  12 zgong  VISA\Domain Users        384 Sep  8 16:46 gradle-5.4.1
-rw-r--r--   1 zgong  VISA\Domain Users  132768903 Sep  8 16:46 gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
-rw-r--r--   1 zgong  VISA\Domain Users          0 Sep  6 16:17 gradle-5.4.1-all.zip.lck
-rw-r--r--   1 zgong  VISA\Domain Users          0 Sep  8 16:46 gradle-5.4.1-all.zip.ok
```

BTW, this way below does not work for me

Using system properties can be done in the .gradle/gradle.properties file in the user’s home directory

**Specifying the HTTP Basic Authentication credentials using system properties**

```
systemProp.gradle.wrapperUser=username
systemProp.gradle.wrapperPassword=password
```

**Reference:**
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Answer (score 0):

For the peeps that are using Ionic/Cordova, remove node_modules, platforms, and plugins folders

```
rm -rf node_modules platforms plugins
```

Re-install everything

```
npm i && ionic cordova platform add android
```

After that open `platforms/android/project.properties` file

It was like this for me

```
target=android-29
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1
cordova.system.library.4=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.5=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.6=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.8=androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
cordova.system.library.9=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.10=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.11=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.+
cordova.system.library.12=androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.+
cordova.system.library.13=com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.16.0
cordova.gradle.include.1=onesignal-cordova-plugin/MyApp-build-extras-onesignal.gradle
```

Remove all duplicates and everything that targets `version:+`, so the file looked something like this afterward

```
target=android-29
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.0
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1
cordova.system.library.4=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.8=androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
cordova.system.library.12=androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.13=com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.16.0
cordova.gradle.include.1=onesignal-cordova-plugin/Artinove-build-extras-onesignal.gradle
```

Build your project

```
ionic cordova build android
```

And all should work then.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the project gradle folder --> gradle-wrapper.properties
2. change the distributionUrl to another(you can found this in your .gradle\wrapper\dists folder)
3. Click Sync now

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the wrapper, daemon and caches files in `C:\Users\{userName}\.gradle` and the in your Android Studio select the option `File/Invalidate caches and restart` And that's all!!! It worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

I download from the link and locate the gradle to specified location in dowloaded gradle folder

Hope it help :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:-**

go to:

C:\Users{your_user_name}.gradle

And go to each folder and check that your gradle(gradle-x.x-all)

which mentioned in the error exists, delete all the references Gradle package from all folders.

**Then open Android Studio as "Run As Admin"**

**Method 2:-**

go to error message link and download mentioned gradle : https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-x.x.x-bin.zip

after that extract in .gradle\wrapper\dists
and open Android studio again but as "Run As Admin"**

Answer (score 0):

Using a VPN fixed it for me.

After trying most of the already given solutions, I tried downloading that specific version manually from the release page(https://services.gradle.org/distributions/), but I got an error. Checking the console, it was a 401(unauthorized) error.

I downloaded Proton VPN, used the free account and the default location (Netherlands) and retried downloading from the release page, it worked and I retried in Android studio and it was a success.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if it will help anyone else, But after working through each answer and none of them working a full re install of android studio did the trick for me.