# NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized

Tags: java, android, dictionary, fragment

i get an error in logcat when the app tries to to start onLocationChanged, stating that camera update is not initialized, is there something im missing or doing wrong?

all this code works when trying on a separate activity but i need this to work in a fragment for 3 tab.

I appreciate your help and advice, even if this is a silly question

MAP FRAGMENT.CLASS

```
public class Map extends Fragment implements LocationListener{

private MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private Bundle mBundle;
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container, false);

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView = (MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(mBundle);
    setUpMapIfNeeded(inflatedView);

    return inflatedView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBundle = savedInstanceState;

    // LOCATION
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabledGPS = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean enabledWiFi = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
    if (!enabledGPS && !enabledWiFi) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Selected Provider: " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }


}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (googleMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //Enable MyLocationButton of Google Map
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    // Set Map Type
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    //disable Pan Gesture
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   Log.e("onLocationChanged", "called");
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    // locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mMapView.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Logcat

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.o.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.mp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Unknown Source)
        at com.stephenh.daytrack.daytrackstephenh.SwipeViewsAdapter.Map.onLocationChanged(Map.java:122)
        at com.stephenh.daytrack.daytrackstephenh.SwipeViewsAdapter.Map.onCreate(Map.java:88)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:913)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1920)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1117)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5703)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try MapsInitializer.initialize(this);

Comment: i cant use "this" as i get the error 'initialize(android.content.Content)

Comment: try get your context may be this one be useful getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Comment: when changing it to getapplicationContext() i get the following error-     java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.o.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.mp(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Unknown Source)
            at com.stephenh.daytrack.daytrackstephenh.SwipeViewsAdapter.Map.onLocationChanged(Map.java:122)
            at com.stephenh.daytrack.daytrackstephenh.SwipeViewsAdapter.Map.onCreate(Map.java:88)

Comment: could you please try this again but move your code into oncreate not oncreateview

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
        new LatLng(yourLatitude, yourLongitude), zommvalue));
```

Comment: did you do 'import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;' ?

Comment: do SYNC. the project ..check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467155/could-not-install-gradle-distribution-from-https-services-gradle-org-distribu/27467216#27467216

Comment: after doing the sync the logcat comes back with the same error....i think im gonna give up on it and re write it better

Comment: You can update your SDK manager.. I thik there are paroblem with 'android.support.v4.'.. used updated 'android.support.v7.'..try this.

Comment: you can try this... added this..
dependencies { compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'}

Comment: answer your question then