# Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.10

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use gradle build. It gives me error saying that

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
>   Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.10. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/sanjeewa/workspace/Android/UVCCamera/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip

But my gradle-wrapper.properties includes gradle-2.4-all.zip. I have changed it to gradle-2.2-all.zip 
Still same problem.

When I run  gradle -version in terminal Gradle 2.10 shows as version.

How to solve that error??

my build gradle file is

```
 buildscript { 
   repositories { 
       jcenter() 
   } 
   dependencies { 
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' 
   } 
 } 

 allprojects { 
   repositories { 
       jcenter() 
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

1. Open `gradle-wrapper.properties`
2. Change this line:

   ```
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
   ```

with

```
        distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

3. Go to `build.gradle` (Project: your_app_name)
4. Change this line

   ```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:XXX'
   ```

to this

```
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

or

```
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

5. Don't click `Sync Now`
6. From menu choose `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...`
7. Choose first option: `Invalidate and Restart`

Android Studio would restart. After this, it should work normally

Hope it help

Comment: Curios: why 2.0-beta3 instead of 1.5.0?

Comment: i am just using terminal to gradle build. I think no need to invalidate caches.

Comment: @dsh `1.5.1` is the latest stable, but 2.0-beta3 works fine, it's a bit faster. I'm already using AS 1.5 stable with Gradle plugin 2.0-beta3

Comment: @manitaz, try to build your project in Android Studio, please - if it would work, then try by terminal and compare - I mean check if both would work fine. Don't invalidate? ok, so clean and buld again

Answer (score 40):

Current work around is to overrideVersionCheck: In your build.gradle

```
buildscript {

System.properties['com.android.build.gradle.overrideVersionCheck'] = 'true'
     ...
}
```

[Check this link for more Details](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-thinks-2-10-is-less-than-2-2-when-resolving-plugins/13434/1)

Answer (score 23):

**Just Change in** build.gradle file

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

To

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

1. Now `GoTo` -> `menu choose File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`...
2. Choose first option: `Invalidate and Restart`

   Android Studio would restart.

   After this, it should work normally.

Comment: The android studio and gradle version as very messy. In my case, I have to set the version to current latest: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'. My android studio version is: Android studio 2.2RC

Answer (score 15):

Based on
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html ...

The following table lists which version of Gradle is required for each version of the Android plugin for Gradle.
For the best performance, you should use the latest possible version of both Gradle and the Android plugin.

So, the Plugin version with Required Gradle version should be match.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to fix this:

1) Create a new project

2) open the gradle-wrapper.properties file and copy the distributionUrl to your project e.g.:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2-all.zip
```

3) open the build.gradle (Project) and copy the gradle dependency to your project e.g.:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta1'
```

4) File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart (I think a re-sync may have sufficed, but didn't try it)

5) Delete that project you made (optional)

Look, this is a silly way to do things, but Android Studio is free so who am I to complain...

Comment: This worked with IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2, except that an additional line `google()` had to be copied from the fake project's `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `./gradlew` instead of `gradle` to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The android studio and Gradle version looks like very bad managed. And there's tons of version in-capability issues. And the error message is mostly clueless. For this particular issue. The closest answer is from "Jitendra Singh". Change the version to:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

But in my case: Android studio 2.2 RC, I still get another error:

```
Could not find matching constructor for: com.android.build.gradle.internal.LibraryTaskManager(org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated, com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder, android.databinding.tool.DataBindingBuilder, com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension_Decorated, com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler, com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager, org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry)
```

So I went to the maven central to find the latest com.android.tools.build:gradle version which is 2.1.3 for now. So after change to

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}
```

Solved my problem eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I Had similar issue. Every project has his own gradle folder, check if in your project root there's another gradle folder:

```
/my_projects_root_folder/project/gradle
/my_projects_root_folder/gradle
```

If so, in every folder you'll find /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.

Check if in */my_projects_root_folder/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties* gradle version at least match */my_projects_root_folder/ project/ gradle/ gradle-wrapper.properties* gradle version

Or just delete/rename your */my_projects_root_folder/gradle* and restart android studio and let Gradle sync work and download required gradle.