# Failed to sync Gradle project 'Sunshine-Version-2'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am following udacity's android course which ask to download their sunshine project. When I checked it out and imported it into android studio, am not able to open xml files. The console says Failed to syncGradle project. I have attached a screenshot below.

Any idea how I can fix this and why is it so important that I can't even open the xml files?

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the error message's advice?  What happens when you view the SDK manager?  Do you have the appropriate version installed that the project is looking for?

Comment: When I click on Build Project nothing happens. When I click on Open Android SDK Manager I dont anything that indicates something is missing

Comment: Can you verify that the `buildToolsVersion` specified in the project's Gradle file is the build tools version you have installed ?

Comment: Can you point me where can I find these 2 things

Comment: The file `build.Gradle` is located in the root of your project - you can find it by looking in the Project view of Android Studio.  Look in that file for `buildToolsVersion` and make sure you have that same version installed by opening your Android SDK manager.

Comment: @CzarMatt There was no mention of buildToolsVersion in the build.Gradle file. Also how do I check the version from Android SDK Manager?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem.  Here's how I fixed it:

1. First: go to the following stackoverflow link and use piotrek1543's
   answer.

   [Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749299/gradle-version-2-2-is-required-current-version-is-2-10)
2. Then the project will tell you your SDK is out of date.  Click the
   update/sync SDK ribbon.  The SDK will install.
3. Then, it'll say tools
   out of date.  Click the sync tools ribbon.  The tools will install.

It should work after that.