# QTcreator building simple qt project with android profile

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to build simple Qt project with android profile, but receiving strange error:

> Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug/android-build/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtApplication.java:46:
>   error: duplicate class:
>   org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication public class
>   QtApplication extends Application

after `androiddeployqt` run

Comment: Is this just after upgrading the gradle version?

Comment: no first installation, sorry for delay

Answer (score 0):

Right, I'm going to assume this is the same as what has happened to myself:

1. You've upgraded Android Studio which has broken the Qt build for Android.
2. You've managed to solve the issue of upgrading gradle, resolving previous errors. ie from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749299/gradle-version-2-2-is-required-current-version-is-2-10)
3. Now you're getting 'error: duplicate class'.

Solution:

When Qt builds the project all files are stored in 'build-myappname-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug

**Delete** that folder and rebuild the project.

You may need to clean and rerun qmake, but I doubt that is required. I only do that out of habit.

Comment: Good day, thank you very much, very usefull, tried and issue resolved.