# Gradle on macOS

Tags: android, macos, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I am developing an app using Ionic 1, AngularJS and Cordova. When trying to run its Adroid version on macOS, I keep getting Gradle errors. I tried many solutions like these:

- [Ionic users solution](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo-ur-android-sdk/22056)
- [Ionic team solution](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11591)
- [Stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error)

I also uninstalled everything related to Android Studio, including projects and reinstalled, but it had no effect.
Any help would be appreciated.

I am running:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.5
- Ionic 2.2.2 (my project is on Ionic 1)
- Cordova 6.5.0
- java 1.8.0_121
- Latest Android Studio

Terminal, currently, for `ionic run android` shows:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

```
Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/thismac/myapp/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Before trying those solutions, it the message was that it could not find the Gradle Wrapper.

I also have installed Gradle, but my project uses the version installed by Android Studio.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: And the errors are?

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Please, follow instructions in *Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.10*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749299/gradle-version-2-2-is-required-current-version-is-2-10?rq=1]