# Version of gradle while building APK

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I want to compile my Android project in Android Studio 3.0.1
I have Gradle version 2.2
I receive an error while building the APK

> Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:

> The version of Gradle you are using (2.2) does not support the
>   forTasks() method on BuildActionExecuter. Support for this is
>   available in Gradle 3.5 and all later versions.

So I updated Gradle to 3.5 and 4.2 and i have another error :

Message :

> Error:(1, 0) Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 4.2.

How can i build my APK if i have to be in 2.2?

Comment: Are you confused between gradle version and android gradle plugin version ? What is their values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would try cleaning and rebuilding the project, if that fails try some of the things mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34749866/9220124).

Answer (score 0):

You should not confuse gradle plugin for android and gradle version itself.

Try setting 2.2 as gradle version and gradle plugin as 3.5. Should work. Hope it helps :)