# Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 4.4 Error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, progressive-web-apps

I'm following the steps here to package my PWA to submit to the Play Store - https://docs.pwabuilder.com/jekyll/update/2018/02/03/how-to-package-android.html

When I get to this step: "In Android Studio, select Build > Build APK in the menu bar. The APKs are saved in projects/Polyfills/cordova/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/"

I get the error:

> Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 4.4

I've checked `gradle-wrapper.properties` and I am using the right distribution URL: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip

I am by no means a `developer` and completely new to `Android Studio`, so I'd appreciate any help (as descriptive as possible).

Comment: please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749299/gradle-version-2-2-is-required-current-version-is-2-10

Answer (score 4):

Use the following in project level build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

Required Gradle version **4.4** is equivalent to Plugin version **3.1.0+**, as per table below:
[image]

For more details, kindly refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Change the gradle plugin version in your project level `build.gradle` file to 2.0.0 e.g:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

and Invalidate and Restart Android studio.

Comment: Thank you. When doing that I'm then notified Gradle version 2.10 is required. If I then update the disributionUrl to 'gradle-2.10-all.zip', I then get another message to say that is an unsupported version as well. (invalidating and restarting in between)