# Gradle was not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

I was running my projects in android studio latest version 2.2, but my gradle was in 2.1 and I was getting an error shown below. Please help me in solving this

```
Error:Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip'.
```

Comment: Why do you think someone gonna download 55 mb zip file to solve your problem? Please post what's the error are you getting in logcat.

Comment: Have you tried anything serach in SO, see this link you have to try some solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585869/android-studio-error-installing-gradle

Comment: @Kunu, it's not for download, that message is what being displayed on his message screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your Internet conection..

or try with

Tools -> Android -> Sync

or Try

File -> Settings -> Gradle -> Check Offline Work

You can found your anser here below link
[Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467155/could-not-install-gradle-distribution-from-https-services-gradle-org-distribu)