# The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip' does not exist

Tags: android-studio, gradle, gradle-wrapper

In Android Studio, I am getting the following error when trying to run my app on an Android device:

```
The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip' does not exist.
```

All my Android Studio projects are affected by this and restoring them to older commits does not change anything.

The problems all started by following the advice given here: [Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467155/could-not-install-gradle-distribution-from-https-services-gradle-org-distribu)

I deleted everything in my /.gradle/wrapper/dists/ folder. Now, I get the above error and I do not see how to solve it.

Here is how to reproduce it with Android Studio 2021.1.1 on Windows (but be warned: this might corrupt your projects, too):

1. Delete everything in `/.gradle/wrapper/dists/`
2. Create a new project "Test" in Android Studio (this might take a while, since gradle-7.2-bin.zip will be downloaded in the dists folder)
3. The project builds and runs without errors
4. Close Android Studio
5. Delete everything in `/.gradle/wrapper/dists/` again
6. Open project "Test" in Android Studio
7. Try to run

Now you should get the above mentioned error.

At this point, `/.gradle/wrapper/dists/` is still empty. Now you can do the following:

8. run `gradlew tasks` in Terminal in the Project Folder of "Test" (this will take a while, since gradle-7.2-bin.zip will be downloaded in the dists folder again)
9. run `gradlew build` (everything should build without errors)

But clicking on "Run" still yields the same error.

I am getting the impression that this is an AndroidStudio / IntelliJ bug.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Running Android Studio as Administrator solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my Android Studio installation was heavily corrupted. Simply, uninstalling it and installing it again also did not help.

I basically had to do everything that was suggested here: [How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10) and delete everything related to Android Studio. I installed it again and now everything is fine again.

I do not know what the problem was. Maybe the `.m2` folder, maybe the `Jetbrains` folder.

My advice to everyone facing the same issue:
First try around deleting caching folders. If nothing helps, go for the brute force approach and follow the answers (not only the accepted answer) of the above mentioned StackOverflow question.